# Is it possible to create a list of maps in Dart?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to create a list of maps from accessing a JSON file in my program.
Is it possible in Dart, how? 
and if not, could you suggest some alternatives on this?

Answer (score 3):

`List<Map> listOfMaps = [{"name":"Map1"},{"name":"Map2"}];`

The builtin JSON parser does this automatically: [Dartdocs](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_convert/JsonCodec.html#decode)